# How to compare two strings in R?

Tags: r, string, string-comparison

I'm having trouble comparing two strings in R. Is there a method to do it?

Like in Java you have `String.equals(AnotherString)`, is there a similar function in R?

Comment: You can check with `==` or `all.equal` or `identical`

Comment: In addition to the above, would encourage you to edit your question and show us what your strings look like and what you tried so far. Please see: [how to make a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: This [blog](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/01/how-to-compare-strings-in-r-with-examples/) has several ways to compare strings based on what your strings look like.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's pretty simple actually.

```
s1 <- "string"
s2 <- "String"

# Case-sensitive check
s1 == s2

# Case-insensitive check
tolower(s1) == tolower(s2)
```

The output in the first case is `FALSE` and in the second case it is `TRUE`. You can use `toupper()` as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str_equal` from `stringr 1.5.0`. It includes an `ignore_case` argument:

```r
library(stringr)
s1 <- "string"
s2 <- "String"

str_equal(s1, s2)
#[1] FALSE

str_equal(s1, s2, ignore_case = TRUE)
#[1] TRUE
```

`str_equal` uses the [Unicode rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) to compare strings, which might be beneficial in some cases:

```r
a1 <- "\u00e1"
a2 <- "a\u0301"
c(a1, a2)
#[1] "á" "á"

a1 == a2
#[1] FALSE
str_equal(a1, a2)
#[1] TRUE
```